# Common Dialog in VB6 to .net

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am upgrading a VB6.0 app to VB.Net.

Visual studio Express 2005 did an automatic up grade but still there are some lines of code which it was not able to upgrade.

These are mainly CommDiag issues. Please if somebody can suggest something on how I can write it in VB.NET. I am just a starter in VB.net.

Below is the code:

```
Public Function open_file(ByRef form_name As System.Windows.Forms.Form, ByRef file_name As String, ByVal file_type As String, ByRef mode As String, ByRef cap As String, ByRef choice As Boolean) As Byte

    Dim Msg As String 'used to save error messages for the msgbox command
    Dim fileNum As Short 'used to get the next available file number

    '*** handle all errors in the error handler routine
    On Error GoTo open_error_handler

    If (choice = True) Or (file_name = "") Then
        '*** handle the cancel button seperate
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.CancelError = True

        '*** set the 'prompt for overwrite flag' for save dialogs
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.Flags = &H2s

        '*** setup the fields for the common dialog control
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.fileName = file_name
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.DefaultExt = Right(file_type, 3)
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.Filter = file_type
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.DialogTitle = cap
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        form_name.CommDiag.InitDir = basFunctionsIniRegistry.ReadINIString("Default Directories", file_type, "c:\", iniFileLocation)

        Select Case mode
            Case "output"
                '*** display the save box if we'll be writting to the file
                'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
                form_name.CommDiag.ShowSave()
            Case "input", "open", "append"
                '*** display the open box
                'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
                form_name.CommDiag.ShowOpen()
        End Select          
        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control CommDiag could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSExpressCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'
        file_name = form_name.CommDiag.fileName         
    End If
    '*** get next available file number
    fileNum = FreeFile  
End Function
```

Comment: Have you searched for `vb.net common dialog`?

Comment: The upgrade wizard does a good(ish) job but in all honesty the fudges necessary make for terrible code. You should really take the opportunity to re-write it if you can. This is not always possible of course, but it is *really* worth it to get the best out of .net

Comment: Have you made any effort to figure this out yourself (other than running the Upgrade Wizard)?

Comment: Where it says click the links for more information, you should try that.

Comment: Yes i tried to search vb.net common dialog. But i found vb.net dosent support vb6.0 comm diag any more , it has now ColorDialog ,FontDialog,OpenFileDialog,SaveFileDialog , PrintDialog classes that does the functionality of comm diag. The problem is i dont know how to right the ablove code using these classes.

Comment: And yes i tried the links that were there after up-gradation , they are not helpful either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried  and i hope following is the way we can use OpenFileDialog,SaveFileDialog classes for above code in place of CommDiag

```
Public Function open_file(ByRef form_name As System.Windows.Forms.Form, ByRef file_name As String, ByVal file_type As String, ByRef mode As String, ByRef cap As String, ByRef choice As Boolean) As Byte

Dim Msg As String 'used to save error messages for the msgbox command
Dim fileNum As Short 'used to get the next available file number

'*** handle all errors in the error handler routine
On Error GoTo open_error_handler

If (choice = True) Or (file_name = "") Then
    '*** handle the cancel button seperate
    Select Case mode
        Case "output"
         Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

                saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = basFunctionsIniRegistry.ReadINIString("Default Directories", file_type, "c:\", iniFileLocation)
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = file_type
                saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
                saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = Right(file_type, 3)
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = file_name
                saveFileDialog1.Title = cap
                saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()   
        Case "input", "open", "append"
            Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = basFunctionsIniRegistry.ReadINIString("Default Directories", file_type, "c:\", iniFileLocation)
                openFileDialog1.Filter = file_type
                openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
                openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = Right(file_type, 3)
                openFileDialog1.FileName = file_name
                openFileDialog1.Title = cap
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Select          

    file_name = form_name.CommDiag.fileName         
End If
'*** get next available file number
fileNum = FreeFile  
End Function
```